# Java: How to avoid code duplication between display() and write(pdf)

Tags: java, oop, processing

I have two functions within a class

```
void display()
```

and

```
void write(PGraphics pdf)
```

I use `display()` to display elements to the screen. Is there a way of invoking the code within `display()` so that I do not have to write out each of the functions again within `write(pdf)`? e.g.
`line(0,0,100,100)` to `pdf.line(0,0,100,100)` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by drawing to a `PGraphics` image instead of drawing directly to the screen, then draw that image to the screen. That way you could swap it out for the PDF `PGraphics` without changing any code. Something like this:

```
PGraphics pg;
PGraphics pdf;

boolean usePdf = false;

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
  pg = createGraphics(width, height);
  pdf = //whatever
}

void draw(){
   if(usePdf){
      display(pdf);
   }
   else{
      display(pg);
      image(pg, 0, 0);
   }
}

void display(PGraphics g) {
  g.beginDraw();
  g.background(100);
  g.stroke(255);
  g.line(20, 20, mouseX, mouseY);
  g.endDraw();
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Kevin for your input. (this is at least the second time you have helped me with a solution)
This is probably the approach that I like the best. Would the PGraphics print to file as a flat image or vectors though?

Comment: @jackoverflow How the `PGraphics` saves to a file completely depends on the code you write that saves it to a file. You might want to check out the [`PImage`](https://www.processing.org/reference/PImage.html) class for some useful functions for saving images.

Comment: So I’m assuming that if I don’t invoke anything like `loadPixels()` and just use things like `rect(…)` it should just stick to vectors?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use all of the code jsut call it inside (but I guess you don't want to do that)

You should refractor the code and put the stuff you want to use in both methods into it's own method like:

`private void hopefullyIGetABetterName(...) {...}`

You can call this method inside of `display` as well as in `write`
I hope this helps, otherwise feel free to ask :-)

Comment: The problem is that it needs to write to an external pdf object — Ideally my code would be something like `write(PGraphics pdf) { pdf.display();}`

Answer (score 0):

- extract a common interface between drawing to screen and to the PDF  (lets call it `Drawable`)
- Implement `Drawable` for drawing to the screen.
- Implement `Drawable` for drawing to the PDF
- Create a single `draw` method that takes that interface.
- Change `display()` to call `draw(screenDrawable)`
- Change `write(...)` to call `draw(pdfDrawable)`